# How to allow users to choose custom themes in Android app?

Tags: android, colors, toolbar

I want to allow users to change the colour of their toolbar and the splashscreen by going into the settings menu and selecting a pre-defined colour. Right now it opens up a dialog window and lets them select a colour but that is it. I want it so when the user selects the colour, the toolbar changes in colour aswell as a preset coloured splash screen changes. This will now be the theme off the application until the user decides to change the colour again. How can I go about doing this while maintaining compatibility with Android 4.2+?